# iPhone: bulk move ALL voice memos + ALL pdfs generated from Safari page prints (pdf-exports using "Books") to pc

Tags: pdf, mobile-safari, file-transfer, ibooks, itunes-sdk

**voice memos:**

I have 100s of voice memos that I recorded using the Apple voice recorder standard app and I want to get them on my pc altogether in one go.

**pdfs:**

I often save mobile Safari pages as Books which are then automatically saved (very quickly and well-formatted) as pdfs. On a website opened in Safari, you can choose the "send to"- button and then the orange Symbol for books. I have houndreds of self-generated pdfs in ibooks, and I have googled and tested for a longer time how to transfer them to my pc (see the details of these tests in the answer section).

Is there any trick to bulk move ALL voice memos in just one go + ALL pdfs in Books to the pc in just one go? I am happy about ANY way to reach this.

**Please mind: I do not want to save every voice memo / pdf, piece by piece, in a cloud or app nor send each of them, piece by piece, by mail.** This costs too much time and nerves and is not a bulk move.

Comment: I have invested at least 20 hours of my lifetime to transfer my 100s of pdfs that I exported as pdfs from Safari websites to Apple ibooks, without success. I have installed about 5 3rd party softwares that should help in transferring any data you have on the iPhone, none could help out here (and yes, the test versions were valid to test the issue). That is why I am starting a bounty, in order to save again a couple of hours and much more nerves of my lifetime.

Comment: This is now opened at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251534441 as well.

Comment: I could not get a solution from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251534441, thus I gave direct feedback using https://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDFs, I found an alternative solution that requires an iPad and the [FileBrowser](https://apps.apple.com/at/app/filebrowser-document-manager/id364738545) app:

1. On the iPad, activate Stage Manager.
2. Open both the Books app and the FileBrowser app and place them side-by-side.
3. In FileBrowser app, navigate to the desired destination folder for your PDFs (I used my NAS via SMB, other target locations should work as well).
4. In the Books app, navigate to the desired collection of PDFs, select all PDFs.
5. Using drag&drop, drag one of the selected PDFs on the FileBrowser app window.

FileBrowser will first show an import progress bar, and then copy the files to the selected destination folder.

**Caveat**: if some PDFs have the same title, only the first (?) file will be imported using this method. You can still drag these files one by one from Books to FileBrowser, and choose to keep both files. However, this does not work if multiple files are selected.

Tested with iPadOS 17.2.

Comment: Since it is too old, I cannot ask to move this question to Ask Different SE, the Apple Stack Exchange, but I need to reopen it there so that it can be answered again. This question here will perhaps later be deleted, or it will always be kept closed since it is off-topic. Can you answer there at Ask Different [iPhone: bulk move ALL voice memos + ALL pdfs generated from Safari page prints (pdf-exports using "Books") to pc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395277/iphone-bulk-move-all-voice-memos-all-pdfs-generated-from-safari-page-prints/)? That would help others finding the answer.

Comment: To make this clearer, it would be good if you copied and pasted your answer there as well since it was reopened and should be the one that can grow with further answers or remarks. This question here may be deleted over time. The bot will not delete it and I will not delete it myself, but the community or the moderator may do so.

Comment: A good helper to be faster with the FileBrowser is to have a Bluetooth keyboard and mouse. Another way to be much faster is to write a script that checks which file name is already there and copies each file with the needed name.

Answer (score 2):

I found a working solution in Decipher Backup Browser 14. This program might not be the only one achieving the aim, but it does the thing. Whoever finds other programs, please add an answer.

It simply reads out the data from the iPhone backup that you can create with iTunes. The program offers extracting all voice memos, as well as extracting all PDFs in "All PDFs in Backup". In the full version, you can then save them in one go to your pc. Thanks go to the pragmatic e-mail help including the screenshot.

[image: save any selected PDFs in one go]

Another possible solution perhaps is to sync your iBooks with iCloud - perhaps, because there is no working test, neither on Windows nor on macOS.

#### Testing the sync of the Safari pdfs:

(I originally got the info of the possible sync on macOS from the Decipher company, but I assume this is a simple misunderstanding or outdated.)

*I sync iBooks with iCloud, iBooks are part of iCloud's "Manage Storage" option in my iPhone Settings, and still I do not see the pdfs there. On Windows, I do not see any iBooks sign at all in iCloud. iBooks is supposed to be hidden in iCloud Drive according to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296462/locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-drive?newreg=1d6ae7995129403b99e57fe74feae430, but I could not succeed with the help of that link, the answers there are for Apple macOS command line (macOS bash). Then an additional investigation turned out that even if there were a hidden folder on Windows (which does not), it would not help: @ankii was so kind to test this on macOS, the needed pdfs cannot be seen in the macOS hidden iBooks folder either. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395290/locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-drive-on-windows, @ankii:*

> I exported a wikipedia page to iOS iBooks, as pdf. It shows up on iOS
> app. but not on Mac app. that is weird.

***Please, if anyone has managed this iCloud sync on Windows or macOS, answer here, but it seems as if there is no solution.***

####

**The simple reason why all of the normal file transfer tools cannot help, but only those which give you the contents of the iTunes backup, is because the needed pdfs ARE only in the backup. :)**

When you delete such a "Safari-pdf", it will ask you whether you want to delete this from iCloud or if you only want to delete it from the downloads. That is just the standard question for the real e-books, while the "Safari-pdfs" that this thread is about are not part of iCloud anyway.

And it seems as if this will not change in the future, according to https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251534441 discussion results.

##################### Finally:

After having saved all of the PDFs, deleting them in two alternatives:

- Books > Library > Edit > "Select All" on the left (you may also do this inside a specific collection only so that you can filter what you want to delete, you can also multi-select PDFs manually instead of "Select All")
- or delete all by going to Settings --> Passwords & Accounts --> iCloud --> iCloud --> Manage Storage --> Apple Books (mind there are 2 of them, take the first one) --> Delete Documents & Data

#

#

#

**Additional documentation**

##########################################################################

Proof that the bulk move cannot be done without a 3rd party app.

I have tried several 3rd party programs to transfer the pdfs, but none of them find the Safari pdf prints, they only find just the commercial e-books. iTunes does not find them either.

I was asked by a moderator to move the details of what I have already tried to reach a bulk move - and which were at first part of the question - to this answer. This was tested in 04/2020, but the problem will still be the same.

##########################################################################

- iPhone 7, iOS 13.4.1 transfer iBooks pdfs to Windows 10
- either with 3rd party apps or iTunes v. 12.10.5.12
- result: nothing works, only workaround is using Adobe Acrobat or

  iCloud Drive going through each single pdf

**Unsuccessful try only using iBooks and iTunes:**

In iTunes, clicking on your phone symbol, the iTunes pane that appears has a lot of options like overview, music, films... and also third party apps like kindle or acrobat in the last menu point, but there is no iBooks anywhere.

In the main menu, iBooks folder is empty. Right-click on iBooks and "transfer purchases" leads to nothing, of course: I have not bought any pdf, but just printed it from safari. In the settings, in "iTunes and App Store" make sure that "iBooks and audiobooks" are switched on for automatic download.

**Third party apps fail to show iBooks' Safari pdf prints:**

- Tested up to now (few of so many): iMazing, iExplorer, easeus, ApowerManager, Phonepaw, iTools 4.4.5.8
- Only those pdfs that you had actually added from the pc to the phone

  are also in the books folder in the third party apps.
- Those pdfs that are just printed pdfs from safari websites do not appear in the third party apps of iTunes.

**iCloud Drive or Adobe Acrobat app: The current workaround which takes too much time and nerves:**

- Adobe Acrobat v. 20.04.00 app on the iPhone, click on every pdf's 3 dots in the overview in iBooks, save it in Acrobat. Then use iTunes, clicking on your Phone symbol, use the last menu point to get to Acrobat 3rd party app and then mark all pdfs and save them to a folder on your pc.
- You can also use iCloud Drive, AirDrop or the like, works the same and does not need iTunes. Make sure that in your iPhone preferences, iBooks --> iCloud Drive is switched on (this is the standard anyway). Still the same issue with any such solution: no bulk move possible.

Comment: I added a separate question of how to find the iBooks folder in iCloud Drive on Windows: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395290/locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-drive-on-windows

Comment: I can confirm that the program works, there is just a very small issue. iBooks names the PDFs automatically after their first line(s) found in the PDFs which is very nice of course. But Decipher is adding the prefix "Documents_" which makes the filenames too large in about 10 % of the cases, in some cases leaving just a .pd or .p or no ending at all. I have asked, there will come a program update on this.

Comment: Now in Decipher 14, this has been fixed, the files are mostly called according to their datetime of creation, a few have real names, not sure what triggers the difference. Anyway, that little problem is solved, you do not need to rename 10 % of the files anymore.

Comment: I also can confirm that this works. Costs 29.99$ though. But I was able to export 129 books (1.95GB) successfully. I tried to search and find free alternatives, but couldn't.

Comment: @ChuckNorris I had hundreds of pdf printouts from Safari, then it is worth the 30 dollars. You get two lifelong licences (that is, for two Apple devices), and you can install these licences again and again on whatever computer. Mind that iTunes can transfer the commercial books for free. Check iTunes before spending the 30 dollars on transferring books.

Answer (score 1):

In Books, use the "Save to Files" option.  Afterwards, follow [these directions](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/transfer-files-iphone-computer-iphf2d851b9/ios).

Comment: Thank you, as far as I can see, this is working only file by file and is what is described in the last paragraph (workaround using Adobe Acrobat or iCloud Drive, the latter of which is explained in your link). I need a solution that is working for all pdf files in one go. Perhaps I should have made this clearer in the question, I will change it slightly.

Comment: I upvote your answer because I was slightly vague about writing "save it in..." while the function is "Save to Files", and also, it took me a lot of time to find this workaround, I would have been happy about your hint at that time. Still, it is not the answer to the question to do all in one go.

Comment: 04 / 2020. And since then, I am not willing to use it, because I do not want to tip houndreds of times on 3 dots, choose "Save to Files", and then delete that file manually again. This workaround is just good to know in case there will not come up any other solution.

Comment: In Books/PDFs, try Edit > Select All > Move to Books (or another collection) then transfer to PC.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the item "Select All" in Books > Library > Edit > "Select All" on the left! Perhaps I had forgotten about it as it is so obvious? Is it that easy? :) Now I select two test PDFs > middle button "Add to…" > and then I cannot move it to Books as you say, as it is already in Books, I could move it to collections like "Finished" or "Want to Read" or a self-named "New Collection". I added it to a new collection named "Test", to check if the pdfs will show up in Books in iTunes or in iCloud Drive only because they belong to a new collection now, but they do not.

Comment: When you use *Books > Library > Edit > "Select All" on the left*, you cannot use the export item at the bottom right anymore. That is available only if you select a single pdf. Which prevents you from using "Save to Files" to iCloud Drive or Acrobat. Strange that Apple does not offer this for multiple selections, it seems quite on purpose, as it should be technically easy. At least you can use the "Select All" to delete all of the pdfs of a collection in one go, I add this in the answer.